# Serialization and deserialization in Typescript for classes with nested maps

Tags: json, typescript, class-transformer

I have some Typescript code I would like to use as NodeJS, which includes simple classes that have fields that are `Map`'s with of objects. I am trying to use the package **[class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/)** to serialize and deserialize (to JSON and from JSON) my classes, and I am not finding a solution.

In addition the "created" field of the parent class is also NOT transformed into `Date`.

The documentation is not updated, or does not seem to work.

Here is a examples of the classes:

```js
// Type to be used for Unique Identifiers (UID).
export type Uid = string;

export class UidObject {
    // Unique identifier of the object.
    readonly uid: Uid;

    constructor(uid: Uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }
}

export class TimeStampedObject extends UidObject {
    @Type(() => Date)
    readonly created: Date;

    constructor(uid: Uid, created: Date) {
        super(uid);
        this.created = created;
    }
}

export class Profile extends TimeStampedObject {

    /// User display alias.
    readonly alias: string;

    constructor(
        uid: Uid,
        created: Date,
        alias: string,
    ) {
        super(uid, created);
        this.alias = alias;
    }
}

export class Group extends UidObject {

    readonly name: string;

    @Type(() => Map) // What should be used here? 
    readonly profiles: Map<string, Profile>;

    constructor(
        uid: Uid,
        name: string,
        profiles: Map<string, Profile>,
    ) {
        super(uid);
        this.name = name;
        this.profiles = profiles;
    }
}
```

Using the "class-transformer" functions does not seem to convert the "profiles" field into a `Map<Uid, Profile>` but just to `Map<string, any>`.

```
let profiles = new Map();
profiles.set("uid-prof-1", new Profile("uid-prof-1", new Date(), "alias-prof-1"));
profiles.set("uid-prof-2", new Profile("uid-prof-2", new Date(), "alias-prof-2"));

let group = new Group("uid-coco", "Coco", profiles);

let json = instanceToPlain<Group>(group);
let instance = plainToInstance<Group, any>(Group, json);

console.log(group);
console.log("------ After =>");
console.log(instance); // This shows an objets which is not in the correct format.
console.log("-----------");
console.log(instance == group); // This returns false
```

Comment: The [docs](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/#working-with-arrays) describe this case with `@Type(() => Skill) skills: Set<Skill>;`. Does that solution not work for you?

Comment: I works almost as inteded for `Set` (it creates an array and not a Set when transforming back). However it does not work at all for `Map`, instead of creating a Map it just creates a `Profile` and puts inside a key-value entries which are not objects corresponding to the data of the profiles.

Answer (score 0):

@pcba-dev did you find an answer? I have something the like this problem.

```
 @Type(() => MyMapsClass)
```

creates a map in the result that is typed MyMapsClass, not Map<string, MyMapsClass>

I cant leave a comment due to the lack of reputation so I am posting as an answer, which this is this not. This is what I have come to as a work around, with the hope the someone with more knowledge than a newbie like me will post a correct approach.

The code below

- Uses deserialize to create the result
- Overwrites the maps from this result with corrected maps
- Uses Object.assign() to set the values of new, "corrected" instances from the original
- Marks the map in the class with @Type(() => Map<string, MyMapsClass>), not Type(() => MyMapsClass) which is as I read the docs

```
    // could not get deserialize to work, this is temp work around
    let result = deserialize(MyObject, jsonString!);
    let correctedMap = new Map<string, MyMapsClass> ();
    for (let [key, value] of result.resultsMap) {
      let correctMyMapClass = new MyMapsClass();
      Object.assign(correctMyMapClass, value)
      correctedNodeMap.set(key, correctMyMapClass);
    }
    result.MyMapsClass = correctedMap;
```

Comment: I was not able to find a solution. I finally decided to include in all my classes `toJson()` and `fromJson` methods which are then implemented case by case. It is an overkill, but at least using Github Copilot or ChatGPT the coding time is reduced.